# Probability of Defective parts made by 2 suppliers.

Tags: probability

**Supplier A has 2% defects while supplier B has 5% defects. 80% of the products are made using the parts from Supplier A. Given a product is defective, what is the probability that it is made using parts from A?**

Help me out in determining what the numerator I should be using to get the correct answer.

Probability of getting a defective product from A is 2/100 = 1/50

Probability of getting a defective product from B is 5/100 = 1/20

Since, 80% of the products are from A, the probability of getting defective products from the A is (80/100)x(2/100) = 2/125

Then the remaining 20% of the products are from B and the probability of getting defective products from B is (20/100)x(5/100) = 1/100

The total probability of getting defective product is the sum of defective products from A and B

n(s) = [(80/100)x(2/100)]+[(20/100)x(5/100)] = 13/500

Which of the following is the correct approach?

1. (1/50)/(13/500) = 10/13 = 0.76923
2. (2/125)/(13/500) = 8/13 = 0.61538

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You expect $0.8\times 0.02=0.016$ of all the parts to be defective parts from A, and $0.2\times 0.05=0.01$ of all the parts to be defective parts from B, making a total of $0.016+0.01$ of all the parts being defective.  So $\frac{0.016}{0.026}=\frac8{13}$ of the defective parts are expected to come from A.  So approach 2.

Comment: Your $\frac{1/50}{13/500}=\frac{0.02}{0.026}$ in approach 1 is the ratio of rates of defects from A to the overall rates of of defects.  But this is not a proportion or probability: for B the equivalent figure  would be $\frac{1/20}{13/500}=\frac{0.05}{0.026}$ which is greater than $1$ and  impossible to interpret that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Bayes' Theorem
\begin{equation}
 P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}
\end{equation}
where $P(A|B)$ is the probability of $A$ happening given $B$ is true.

In this case the probability of the defective product belonging to A (probability $P(A)$) given there is a defective product (probability $P(D)$) is

\begin{equation}
 P(A|D) = \dfrac{P(D|A)P(A)}{P(D)} = \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{50}\cdot\dfrac{80}{100}}{\dfrac{13}{500}} = \dfrac{80}{130} = \dfrac{8}{13}
\end{equation}

Comment: Formatting tip:  Typing `$P(A \mid B)$` produces $P(A \mid B)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!